# How to override a route in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I've two controller controllerOne is defined under an area AreaOne . I need to reroute one of the action defined in the controllerOne to the action defined in controllerTwo I tried attribute routing but its not working. my current code is given below

**Action In Controller One**

```
 public class ControllerOne
    {   public ActionResult CustomerSearch()
    {

                return View("Search", model);
    }
}
```

**Action In Controller Two**

```
[Route("AreaOne/ControllerOne/CustomerSearch")]
     public class ControllerTwo
        {   public ActionResult CustomCustomerSearch()
        {

                    return View("Search", model);
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve this.?

Comment: Why not just move the controller to the other area?

Comment: @jasen if I can then I wouldn't be here

Answer (score 2):

In RouteConfig.cs you can use routes.MapRoute to associate your URL with any controller & action in your project.

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "OverrideCustomerSearch",
                url: "AreaOne/ControllerOne/CustomerSearch",
                defaults: new { controller = "Two", action = "CustomCustomerSearch" }
        );
```

Comment: Already tried this the problem with this I've to write route mapping for every method in my controller. I'm looking for something a little more generic

Comment: Are you trying to make it so your 'ControllerOne' never gets hit? Are you able to name the methods in ControllerTwo with the same names as ControllerOne? You can make the MapRoute function more generic (e.g. as it is in the default {controller}/{action}/{id} route).